# Delphi XE5 Firemonkey Video Frame Grab and Display

Tags: delphi, windows-8.1, video-capture, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

There's a Stackoverflow thread elsewhere that points out that Firemonkey has to display video through the primary thread.  I am trying to use a DirectX camera to snag a series of images (in Win8.1 for now--other OS's can wait).  So I use the SampleBufferReady and SampleBufferSync approaches in the Embarcadero example code (that just has a TImage on a form), but with enough changes that I never see anything.  I need to do my display in a TImageViewer; pointing the tbitmap in the SampleBufferSync at that tbitmap is easy.  But nothing displays.  From a procedural viewpoint, pseudocode of what I want is

```
setup whatever
camera.startcapture 
repeat
 repeat until framecaptured {what SampleBufferReady should do -- only fire when ready}
 Imageviewer.repaint {inside SampleBufferReady?}
 inc(mycounter) {inside SampleBufferReady?}
until (mycounter>mylimit) or (user interrupts video input)
camera
```

One could add a ttimer to slow things down.  What I don't "get" is

- must I define my own TEvent to find out that the camera's snagged an image, or does this even already exist?  I would have thought that SampleBufferReady would respond to the arrival of an image and I could process whatever inside that event.
- to display an image in something other than a TImage, will I need to turn off the camera, paint the bitmap, then turn the camera back on?  If so, will I need to have SampleBufferReady contain a command to turn the camera off?  Boy, does that sound clunky!

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

here is a complete code source that i test the c++ version that is same as pascal in term of function calls and mechanism, only the syntax differ:
[download here the pascal version](http://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tree/branches/RadStudio_XE6/Object%20Pascal/Mobile%20Snippets/AccessCameraApp/).

the code work fine for both android and desktop( i test the c++ version). so download, test and confirm for me the pascal code.